# Selenium tests always want to open localhost

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I want to place my playFw app to a test server and want to run tests on it.
The problem is, no matter what I write to these application.conf properties: application.baseUrl, application.url, the selenium test runner tries to open localhost.

For example, my test app runs on a server under this url: http://testapp.example.com.
So I can open the playFw tests page opening this url: http://testapp.example.com/@tests, it works fine, I can select which tests I want to run.
When a selenium test is running, and it tries to open a page from my app the following error message appears:
`open   http://localhost:9000/event/abouttheevent   Object #<HTMLIFrameElement> has no method 'getCurrentWindow'`

The selenium test runner tries to open the page from localhost. In the selenium test file I use `open('@@{Event.abouttheevent()}')`

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is [hardcoded as baseUrl](https://github.com/playframework/play1/blob/master/modules/testrunner/app/views/TestRunner/index.html#L365) (in multiple places) in the Selenium test runner. I'm not sure why they chose this, but you could [file a bug](http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/new) to get an answer on that from one of the developers.

Your only alternative at this point would be to set up an auto-test environment, which is made to run on servers, so wouldn't give these issues. Or run the tests locally.